# IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program,error=13, permission deny

Tags: android

When I try Platform and plugin Updates, the Event log said:

> IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/home/xieyi/LinuxSdk/platform-tools/adb": error=13, 权限不够(permission
>   deny).

What is wrong? I am running as a root, why permission deny?

Comment: Please provide more information on the steps you are taking - it is unclear what you are asking currently.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution is to change permission in ubuntu:)**

Go to Platform-Tools directory of android sdk.
/Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ls

This will show you adb is not in green color. So execute 
/Android/Sdk/platform-tools# chmod +x *

after this restart studio and again check in command line with pervious command ls, now you will notice adb would be in green color.

Hope this will work for you :) enjoy

Comment: Worked for me! Also had to change the permissions of files in build-tools directory of Sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo chmod -R 777 /name-of-root-directory-containing-SDK`